# SQL group by and where on each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with columns like sourceId (guid), state (1:Deactivated, 2:Activated, 3:Dead), modifiedDate.

I am writing a query to *group by sourceId* and see if ALL the records in a group have the state as 2 (activated) and also get the MAX of modifiedDate of the rows which have state as 2 (activated) in each group.

result table should be something like sourceId, IsAllActivated, MaxModifiedForActivatedRecords.

I tried a lot of options like Partition By, Cross over etc. which are giving me either one of the column and not both. Options which have self joins were costly, so looking for any other efficient way of forming the query.

Data :

SourceId   | State   | modifiedDate

s1        | 1        | 01/01

s1        | 2        | 01/02

s2        | 3        | 02/03

s2        | 3        | 03/03

s1        | 3        | 10/10

Ouput:

sourceId | IsAllActivated | MaxModifiedForActivatedRecords

s1       | 0              | 02/03

s2       | 1              | 03/03

What i had tried :

```
SELECT
[SourceID]
,CASE
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT State) = 1 AND 
    SUM(DISTINCT State) = 3
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS IsAllActivated
FROM ThreadActivation
GROUP BY SourceID

SELECT
[SourceID]
,MAX(modifiedDate) AS MaxModifiedForActivatedRecords
FROM ThreadActivation
GROUP BY SourceID
HAVING State = 3
```

I am able to get them separately, but not together in a single query.

I tried ranking with row number :

```
WITH ThreadActivationTransaction AS (
        select 
         *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY SourceId order by modifiedDate desc) AS rk
        from ThreadActivation)
        select 

        [sourceID]
      ,CASE 
          WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT State) = 1 AND SUM(DISTINCT State) = 3 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0
       END AS IsAllActivated
      ,[SourceId]
    from ThreadActivation s
        GROUP by SourceId  --where s.rk =1
```

All these were not giving me a break through.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to the forum and I am only a few questions old. I had tried a lot before I came to the community for a solution. I had no intentions of just getting the answers without proper research effort.

Comment: I would like to know more if there is any other efficient way of doing this too @KenWhite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and `case`:

```
select sourceId,
       (case when max(state) = min(state) and max(state) = 2
             then 1 else 0
        end) as IsAllActivated,
       max(case when state = 2 then modifiedDate end) as MaxModifiedForActivatedRecords
from t
group by sourceId;
```

This assumes that `state` is not `NULL`.  The logic is only slightly more complicated if that is possible.

Comment: So cool..! I din't know we can do a CASE inside MAX. Thank you so much.

Comment: Say if i am looking for a flag called IsAllDead (which mean, i am looking if all the threads are dead in a group - grouped by sourceid), can it not be just min(state) = 3    instead of max(state) = min(state) and max(state) = 3